# Proper type annotation for an object that can be unpacked with the * operator?

Tags: python, types, mypy

What is the proper type annotation for an object that should be unpacked with the `*` operator, i.e. `foo` in this (random) example:

```
def some_function(foo):
    ... = bar(*foo)
```

I know that `*` can unpack tuples and lists, but is it limited to these two classes or does it have any kind of interface that would make it usable for other collections?

Comment: Would `typing.Iterable` suffice?

Comment: No, that would mean that even strings are unpackable, but that raises a SyntaxError.

Comment: Strings are unpackable though.

Comment: @gmolau: strings are unpackable, all iterables are unpackable (well if the iterable never ends it will of course result in a memory error).

Comment: How does it work for strings? I tried `*'foo'`.

Comment: @gmolau It works just fine.

Comment: e.g. `(lambda *args: args)(*'abc')`

Comment: @gmolau: well then you call `bar(..)` with `bar('f', 'o', 'o')` since a `str`ing is an iterable of its characters (which are strings as well). You can use `list(some_iterable)` to obtain the elements of that iterable in a list, so `list('foo')` gives `['f', 'o', 'o']`.

Comment: Well yes, a string is an iterable which can be turned into a list which can then be unpacked. But I cannot unpack a string directly with `*'some_string'`, because that gives a `SyntaxError: can't use starred expression here`, even though that was really the point of the unpack operator, wasn't it? Is it documented anywhere in what circumstances one can use the `*`? I can only find this short explanation, which doesn't go into much detail: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Python unpacks *any* iterable (so a `list`, `str`ing, `tuple`, `dict`ionary, etc.). You thus can use an [**`Iterable`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#generics) for that, like:

```
from typing import Iterable

def some_function(foo : Iterable):
    bar(*foo)
```

In case the items that are unpacked should be of a specific type, you can specify this between square brackets, like:

```
# given the items that are unpacked should all be ints

from typing import Iterable

def some_function(foo : Iterable[int]):
    bar(*foo)
```

Comment: I have a question myself. Is there a good reason to use `typing.Iterable` over `collections.abc.Iterable` as long as you don't want to specify the content (e.g. `Iterable[int]`) of the iterable?

Comment: @timgeb: good question! I think it does not make any difference, but personally I like the `typing` more, since this is designed towards the purpose of type signatures.